# GridView with too much text

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that pulls data out of the database and populates its fields automaticaly.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataSourceID="DS" PageSize="1"  CssClass="q">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" Height="20"  CssClass="q"/>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" Height="15px" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Some of the fields are too long. Is there any way to cut the length of the text and insert a button that pops-up a new window with text?
The gridview aslo generates Edit and Delete buttons. Pressing an Edit button gives me little texboxes. How can I work around them to make the same button with a popup window for editing?

Another way that I thought of was creating a textarea with scrollbar. I know how to add a field with a scrollbar manually but it is created as a label, so when I press Edit, this field is not editable. And again, it is manual, but my gridview is auto populated. How can I populate large fields with textareas with scrollbars automatically?

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

---

Okay, so I found a solution for shortening text:

```
protected void gvData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            ViewState["OrigData"] = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
            if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Length >= 30)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Substring(0, 30) + "...";
                e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = ViewState["OrigData"].ToString();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Then add OnRowDataBound="gvData_RowDataBound":

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
 GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
 AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataSourceID="DS" PageSize="1"  
 OnRowDataBound="gvData_RowDataBound">
```

This cuts the length to 30 characters and displays the full text in the ToolTip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the second part:

```
    protected void gvData_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.gvData.EditIndex != -1)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();

        for (int i = 0; i < gvData.Rows[gvData.EditIndex].Cells.Count; i++)
            try
            {
                tb = (TextBox)
                    gvData.Rows[gvData.EditIndex].Cells[i].Controls[0];

                if (tb.Text.Length >= 30)
                {
                    tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                }
            }
            catch { }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this post, I think it could be useful.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/051887c6-2d87-4361-a5a1-cd5213609673/

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention, I am making a web application, not a form. But thanks for the link!

Comment: haha, ok so maybe this link could be usefull http://techybit.com/index.php/applications/gridview-ajax-popup-code/

Comment: This is pretty much hard coded. I have about 30 fields and they may change from time to time...